# What happens with the number of protons inside a wire in movement?

Tags: special-relativity

In Special Relativity we solve the problem of the moving wire with an electrical current saying the protons inside the wire have a higher density: hence the wire is not neutral anymore (and we exchange a force caused by a B field with a force caused by an E field):

[https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-*Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World*(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/24%3A_The_Theory_of_Special_Relativity/24.05%3A_Electric_and_magnetic_fields_and_Special_Relativity](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/24%3A_The_Theory_of_Special_Relativity/24.05%3A_Electric_and_magnetic_fields_and_Special_Relativity)

[image]

But if the density of protons is higher, then the number of protons must be higher too, so changing the frame of reference is also creating new protons?

How can we explain the higher density without adding extra protons?

Answer (score 3):

Normally this idea is presented in the case of a wire that is infinitely long. That gives the problem a translational symmetry and makes everything simpler. For an infinite wire, the number of protons is infinite. If you change to a different frame, the number is still infinite, but with a different density. This is similar to Hilbert's hotel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel

Comment: Aw, beat me to it by a few minutes. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual presentation of this derivation, the wire is infinite in length, which means that the total number of protons in the wire is infinite. Increasing the proton density in the wire is not a problem in this case, because the "total number" of protons is "the same". No proton creation is necessary, because an infinite wire with 1 proton/unit length and an infinite wire with 2 protons/unit length both have a countably infinite number of protons.

This is very similar to the discussions about infinity that arise in "Hilbert's Hotel": in a hotel with rooms labeled 1,2,..., you can accomodate any additional number of guests you want without having to create additional rooms.

Comment: ok, but what happen in a "real" wire then? not an infinite one

Comment: correction , protons not photons: @Enrique In the rest frame of the wire, the number of protons is constant. It is in the rest frame of the observer that changes appear, I would think that due to the length contraction of the wire, the density computed by the observer at rest goes up , but the number of protons is the same

Comment: @annav but that's exactly my question, if density is higher and the wire is not infinite, then the number or protons must be higher too

Comment: @Enrique No. Density is computed higher. i.e. N/volume. because due to the relativistic length contraction that the observer at rest sees, the volume is smaller, so for the observer at rest the density computed by the observer is  larger for the same number of protons.

Comment: @annav yes I understand that, but then what happen with the electrons? they are in the same "volume" of the wire, so if you say the protons has higher density in the same volume then there are more protons than electrons

Comment: @Enrique  The difference in the observed charge distribution is what makes for the various effects of electromagnetic radiation, seen in the rest system of the observer it  comes from the relativistic moving system of the wire . We are dealing with four momentum vectors, velocity and momentum are not the same

Comment: @annav can you add an answer with more details? My problem understanding this is: if the wire is finite, then if we say the wire is "charged" that means there are more protons than electrons right? (is not only related to density if the wire is not infinite). You can just look at the image in my question, suppose the wire ends there, you can clearly see there are more protons than electrons, is this also an effect in relativity? I mean, the creation of new particles is a relativistic effect?

Comment: The image does not represent reality. Lorentz transformations do not change particle numbers for particles that have conserved quantum numbers, as are protons electrons .The distribution of charge can change, not the conserved numbers.  . I do not think I can be clearer in an answer.

Comment: in the electron frame, the protons are contracted by gamma, and the electrons are spread out by gamma. If you draw a minkowski diagram with 2 protons going vertically and 2 electron going off at $\tan{\beta}$, both with unit spacing, and then draw a boosted set of axes, you will see at fixed $t'$, the distance between the 2 proton lines is less, and the 2 electron lines is greater. Moreover, the tilted $t'=0$ will show that the  plane of simultaneity explains why it is neutral in the lab frame, and charged in all others moving along the wire.

Comment: Let's put in another way (even supposing the wire is infinite): the observers must count the number or protons and electrons (or at least say if there are more protons than electrons). What do you think will happen? if the "moving" observer sees a higher density of protons, always, at every moment, when the wire is moving, so at every position of the wire is seeing a higher density of protons, what will be the conclusion for him? there are more protons than electrons, that's why the wire is charged right? How can explain higher density at every position without different quantities p+ e-?

Answer (score 1):

> But if the density of protons is higher, then the number of protons must be higher too, so changing the frame of reference is also creating new protons? How can we explain the higher density without adding extra protons?

Here is an electric circuit according to an observer standing still:  O
Here is the same electric circuit according to an observer moving past it: 0

Let's say the observers are at the center of the O or 0. Now we can see that the moving observer sees protons packed together when he looks up or down.

To clarify what "up" means, here is a picture of an observer standing up like a stick: |

At his left and his right he sees protons being extra close to himself. That has no effect though, because the electric fields of protons have changed shape too. Still standing proton's electric field: O Moving protons electric field: 0

Answer (score 1):

In the frame moving with the current, the hyperplane of simultaneity (aka 'now') is tilted to the lab's future (past) in the downstream (upstream) direction.

OR: If you are in the lab frame, every time an electron leaves the wire (event B) at the downstream end, one enters to replace it at the upstream end (event A), thereby maintaining  neutrality. A and B are simultaneous in the lab.

In the current frame, B occurs before A.

Answer (score 1):

The density $\rho$ of the protons increase with the factor $\gamma$, but the length $L$ of the wire decreases with the same factor. So the total number of protons will be unchanged: $(\gamma\rho)*(L/\gamma) = \rho L$.

Comment: and what about the number of electrons then? is the opposite right? how can explain a wire charged without seeing more protons than electrons?